# How to change the behavior of system objects

Tags: vbscript

I am new to Visual Basic and I was wondering how to change the default behavior of system objects. What I am trying to accomplish is "patching" some system functionalities such as downloading via HTTP or starting a process.

I managed to write a piece of code that I thought it may accomplish what I want to do but with no success (I couldn't make it work)

```vb
Function PatchedMethod(Method, Url)
    WScript.Echo Method, Url    
End Function

Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")

'//patching
Set xHttp.Open = GetRef(PatchedMethod)

xHttp.Open "GET", "https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png", False
```

Some Python equivalent snippet of what I want to accomplish is

```python
import urllib.request

def mockup_urlopen(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Trying to download {}".format(args[0]))
    exit()

urllib.request.urlopen = mockup_urlopen
r = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.python.org/static/img/python-logo.png")
```

Comment: That's not possible in VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in VBScript are not "first-class objects" like they are in other languages such as JavaScript. You can't just reassign them. The standard way to wrap a COM object to extend functionality is to compose it in your own class. That is, create a VBScript [Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/4ah5852c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) which exposes methods for the functionality that your code need, and that internally calls the "real" object you're wrapping via encapsulation. Then, your code uses instances of the class to do their work rather than the internal object.